# How to send/receive files via Bluetooth using commands/Terminal?

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, phone, transfer

I have installed Bluetooth dongle software and
with the help of commands (using a terminal), I want to send and receive files from a smartphone.

How can I pair my devices and send files over Bluetooth using Terminal?

Answer (score 22):

**Send files**:

```
bluetooth-sendto --device=12:34:56:78:9A:BC filename
```

To know your device name (12:34:56:78:9A:BC), you can issue this command:

```
hcitool scan
```

**Receive files:**

Haven't found it yet, but will let you know if it can be done using terminal

*edit*:

it looks like it can't be done through terminal. [Blueman](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blueman/) seems to do the trick but it's in GUI

Comment: I have "blueman-sendto" instead of "bluetooth-sendto".

Answer (score 10):

I tested this with Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04) and Android Lollipop.

1. **Ubuntu**. Install the needed **packages**:

   ```
   sudo apt install bluez bluez-tools
   ```

   bluez-tools come with the following tools: `bt-adapter` `bt-agent` `bt-device` `bt-network`
2. **Ubuntu.** Turn on the **visibility**:

   ```
   bt-adapter --set Discoverable 1
   ```
3. **Smartphone.** Scan for **remote devices** to ID your Ubuntu machine.
4. **Ubuntu.** Prep for managing **incoming requests** interactively with:

   ```
   bt-agent
   ```
5. Pair devices:

   1. **Smartphone.** Initiate pairing request;
   2. **Ubuntu.** Accept the request from the bt-agent screen.
6. **Ubuntu.** **Send files** to smartphone with:

   ```
   bt-obex -p [remote_mac] [file]
   ```

   where [remote_mac] is the mac address of the smartphone. For example:

   ```
   bt-obex -p F0:6B:CA:A2:C4:69 ~/book.pdf
   ```
7. **Receive files** from your smartphone:

   1. **Ubuntu** First create a Bluetooth file (obex) server:

      ```
      bt-obex -s [path]
      ```

      [path] is where to download files. For example:

      ```
      bt-obex -s ~/Downloads
      ```
   2. **Smartphone.** Send the file;
   3. **Ubuntu.** Accept the request from the bt-agent screen.

Comment: Still, the bt-obex command is non-interactive, asking to type 'y' for each file to be accepted, which can be annoying. However, as it is a command-line tool, you can create a long file `yyy.txt` containing only lines with the y letter, and then run: `cat yyy.txt | bt-obex -s ~/Downloads`. Your computer will accept all files over bluetooth without asking!

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `yes` command

Comment: Thanks for this!  I also had to install the `bluez-obexd` package.  My received files also ended up in `$USER/.cache/obexd/` rather than the specified directory.

Comment: I keep seeing `bt-obex: obex service is not found
Did you forget to run obexd?` when running `bt-obex` commands. I tried starting it with `systemctl --user` but then it complains that it's already running!

Comment: You can also use the name of the phone with `-p` and find out both name and MAC with `bluetoothctl devices`

Answer (score 1):

This works on my computer:

```
bluedevil-sendfile -u /org/bluez/hci0/dev_<address with underscores instead of colons> -f <file_with_absolute_path>
```

For example:

```
bluedevil-sendfile -u /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_FF_00_FF_00_FF -f /home/tux/test.pdf
```